# CouchDB Map/Reduce Error on what seems to be a simple query

Tags: json, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a VERY simple map/reduce I need to accomplish. I need to get a list of all unique docType values in our database. However, as soon as I add the Reduce function, I get the following error:

```
"Expression does not eval to a function." etc.
```

I'm following the examples from the CouchDB Cookbook and WIKI, and this is stupid simple, so I'm not sure why it's failing.

The map code is as follows:

```
function(doc){ if(doc.docType) emit(doc.docType,1); }
```

This returns every docType without any distinct grouping yet.

The reduce is direct from the samples I've seen:

```
function reduce(key,values){ return null; }
```

This immediately throws the error above... What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding handler functions in CouchDB, you should not include a function identifier, treat it as you would an anonymous function. (it has to do with how CouchDB evals your string into a JS function, of which I do not know the specifics off-hand)

So, for your reduce function, leave off the `reduce` identifier.

```
function (keys, values) {
  return null;
}
```